# Upgrading from PHP 5.2.9-2 to 5.6.29 on IIS 7, Windows Server 2008

Tags: php, iis-7, windows-server-2008, php-5.6, php-5.2

We have a web server that is currently running Windows Server 2008 Standard and IIS 7. It is a self-hosted Wordpress website. We have been running PHP version 5.2.9-2 for a while now and were recently told that this is a security issue and that we should be on PHP 5.6.

I researched online and have seen a lot of information about installing PHP from scratch on a web server, but I haven't found much about upgrading an existing install, especially going from one as old as 5.2 to 5.6.

Is there anything we should be aware of in doing this type of upgrade? Or would the process go pretty much the same as if it weren't such a large version jump, drag and drop the new files, update the php.ini, etc.?

Comment: Yes, and that's all documented here: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php - (note: this same doc exists for 5.4 to 5.5, 5.3 to 5.4, etc, so be sure to review them all).  Basically, in the version change you are referring to, there's a handful of changes that could be "breaking", and you need to test / update your code to ensure that your code won't be affected.  The biggest one you are going to face is that `mysql_` is deprecated.

Comment: Probably worth recommending evaluating version updates more than once a decade.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, I strongly recommend that you set up an environment with PHP 5.6 and *test all of your code* before you update your production web server.

Comment: That's a pretty huge update since 5.2 was released in 2006.  Not something that is going to be able to be covered in a SO answer, hire a migration expert if you're worried about compatibility with production systems.

Comment: @cale_b I've looked at that guide and I don't think any of the changes since 5.2 will break any of our code (other than mysql_ being deprecated).    That guide has a lot of information on what's changed, but I didn't see anything in it on actually doing the upgrade, unless I missed something.

Comment: @Devon I'm not too worried about compatibility; I think most of our code will be fine. I'm just wondering about the actual upgrade process.

Comment: @Mike - Be sure to check the "Backward Incompatible Changes" section.   Your question - whether or not you understand the significance of it - is much more about *ensuring your code will work*.  Trust me when I tell you that I've had to deal with lots of PHP code that "broke" when the PHP version was upgraded this significantly.  You're going up 4 minor versions, which is a big deal.  As for actually upgrading the PHP version - that has been asked and answered in several places, one of which is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/670772/how-to-upgrade-to-php-5-5-on-windows-server-2008

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on serverfault.com (and has been asked / answered there: http://serverfault.com/questions/670772/how-to-upgrade-to-php-5-5-on-windows-server-2008)

Comment: @cale_b I thought there was a separate site for server related questions, couldn't think of the name of it. Whoops..

Comment: @cale_b I actually had that very question up in another browser tab window to look at. Since that was a more minor upgrade (5.4 to 5.5) wasn't sure if there was anything extra to look out for. I'll look at it more thoroughly.